# Select all subscribers who haven't opened an email using MySQL and multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I want to select all subscribers who belong to a certain user and **haven't** been sent an email in the past year. My database is structured like so:

```
Table: email_list_subscribers
Fields: subscriberid, listid, emailaddress

Table: email_lists
Fields: listid, name, ownerid

Table: email_list_subscriber_events
Fields: eventid, subscriberid, listid, eventownerid, eventdate, eventtype
```

So this is how I'm wording my problem:

Select all email_list_subscribers who belong to an email_list with an ownerid of 2 and who don't have an entry in email_list_subscriber_events that is within the last year and an eventtype equal to "Opened an Email Campaign"

So as you can see this quite a complicated query that I just can't get my head around. I've managed to select all subscribers with the correct owner and older than 1 year but can't incorporate that they haven't opened an email.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Select all email_list_subscribers
SELECT 
   es.*
FROM
   email_list_subscribers AS es
-- have an entry in email_list_subscriber_events that is 
   LEFT JOIN email_list_subscriber_events AS ee ON (
      ee.subscriberid = es.subscriberid
-- an eventtype equal to "Opened an Email Campaign"
      AND ee.eventtype = 'Opened an Email Campaign'
-- within the last year
      AND ee.eventdate > CURENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
      )
-- who belong to an email_list with an ownerid of 2
WHERE
   es.listid = 2
-- and who don't have an entry in email_list_subscriber_events ...
   AND email_list_subscriber_events.subscriberid IS NULL;
```